# Proving sine and cosine series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would one prove that 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(cn)}{n}$$
and
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(cn)}{n}$$
are convergent series for any $0 < c \leq 2 \pi$?
It seems like it'd be true based on graphs, but I don't know what test to use.

Comment: This is proved in the section '$(C)$ and $(S)$ series ' in Edward's Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is true when $c\in(0,2\pi)$. Consider the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(cn)+\sin(cn)i}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{icn}}n.$$This series converges by Dirichlet's test:

- the partial sums of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{icn}$ are bounded, since, if $N\in\Bbb N$,\begin{align}\left|\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{icn}\right|&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\left(e^{ic}\right)^n\right|\\&=\left|\frac{e^{ic}-\left(e^{ic}\right)^{N+1}}{1-e^{ic}}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac2{|1-e^{ic}|};\end{align}
- the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic;
- the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ coverges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. If you don't mind me asking, why are the partial sums of the series bounded? What are they bounded by?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.